# where can I install the latest TPL library from

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have been searching for some time now, Could some on eprovide me a dwnload link to the latest TPL.

Answer (score 4):

Latest TPL is integrated in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Or 4.5 depending on what you can use.

Answer (score 2):

`TPL` (Task parallel Lib) has been introduced in .NET 4.0 in order to address/ease complex threading scenarios in CLR/.NET. Having said that, the `Reactive Extensions` for .NET 3.5 SP1 from Microsoft [Source 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx), [Source 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) has System.Threading.dll assembly to support TPL for .NET 3.5.